# Is there a reliable English translation of "Foundations of Geopolitics" by Aleksandr Dugin?

Tags: russian-federation, geopolitics

This book is apparently fairly influential in Russia:

> Few books published in Russia during the post-communist period have exerted such an influence on Russian military, police, and foreign policy elites as Aleksandr Dugin’s 1997 neo-fascist treatise Osnovy geopolitiki: Geopoliticheskoe budushchee Rossii (Foundations of Geopolitics: The Geo-political Future of Russia). The impact of this intended “Eurasianist” textbook on key Russian elites testifies to the worrisome rise of fascist ideas and sentiments during the late Yeltsin and the Putin periods.
>
> <sub>[Russia’s New—and Frightening—“Ism”](https://www.hoover.org/research/russias-new-and-frightening-ism), by John B. Dunlop.</sub>

I am looking for an English translation of the book, but I have been unable to find a reliable one. There is [one on Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/Foundations-Geopolitics-Geopolitical-English-Translation/dp/1521994269/), but it appears to be highly problematic. It does not list a translator, and the text is of very poor quality:

> But, nevertheless, still geopolitics and could not get into the category of conventional obschepriz nannyh Sciences. The first geo-political work of the German Ratzel, Swede Kallen and especially the Englishman Mackinder met with hostility by the scientific community.

As the reviewers on Amazon point out, this seems like the output of Google Translate, not the work of a professional translator.

Has "Foundations of Geopolitics" by Aleksandr Dugin ever been reliably translated into English?
*If not, why not*?

Comment: This is an experiment, based on a [Literature Stack Exchange question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3668/8) that was [received poorly](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/897/8). I believe we can do better. That said, feel free to moderate it as you see fit.

Comment: A good strategy (IMO) is to look in library catalogues. The entry for a translation will usually give the original title; and in any case, you can search by author. Unfortunately, it seems both LOC and libraries in the UK only have the Russian original. Very likely that there is no English translation.

Comment: Is request for resources actually on-topic here? I thought they were offtopic.

Comment: Honestly, not sure @user4012. This is part of the experiment. On the one hand, there are all sorts of troubles associated with recommendation requests - the more popular type of resources requests. On the other, I feel this question can be answered factually, there's very little room for opinion-based answers. I don't see why it should be off-topic, although I could be convinced to close it if it encourages recommendation requests.

Comment: To help answering the "why": not much is translated to english.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_Translationum (compare english as target language / english as original). Note that the fact that the english is widely used in the world could make translation to english **more** likely than translation from english.

Comment: "...unable to find a reliable one." Reliable means here by some kind of professional translator??

Comment: @Trilarion, Reliable might mean more meticulous, unbiased, or truer to the spirit of a source text.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this topic as I myself was looking for an English translation of "Foundations of Geopolitics" by A. Dugin to share with my English-speaking friends, and when it became clear that there is no available translation in English, I decided to take it on myself as I speak and write in Russian and English fluently. The translated version will most likely be coming in a few weeks. Updates will be posted here.

Comment: Since there is no link to even partial work, this answer itself is somewhat speculative.  Please, link to at least a partially completed work, or work in-progress, when it becomes available.  This is not a non-answer, but I think until there is something to show, this is a low-quality answer.

Comment: Is this project still underway? Can I support it with technical assistance?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Ping - anything happened since November @political992 ?

Comment: @political992 any updates

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer:

- Searching the book's title in Google image yields a single book cover (well, two actually: one for the paperback, and a very similar one for the Kindle version).
- The book in question was published 2 months ago (Aug 1st 2017 according to the Amazon page you linked to, Jul 24th 2017 for the Kindle edition according to Goodreads). The same Google image search up to a time before that confirms this translation is indeed recent.

So methinks no, there is no other English translation (yet).

(Wikipedia has a [brief summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_Geopolitics) until there is.)

Comment: Not sure how the publication date of the Amazon translation is relevant? The original was published in 1997.

Comment: @yannis: I took it as meaning that the book was only recently translated for the first time. Which gets confirmed if you restrict the Google image search to before the publication date.

Comment: A risky assumption. For one, translations many have been published under different titles.

Comment: @yannis: it's an assumption, but seeing that the Google image search also yields the Russian cover, I'd expect Google to return slight variations.